# Sending large files Client to Server

Tags: java, sockets, client

I'm trying to send files to my server. I got it working with files smaller than 100mb. Otherwise I ran out of heap. So I remade it but can't really get it to work. I also got the to work except for reading the last data I get stuck in bis.read(buffer) because it didn't know when the file ended. So I tried to send the length of each segment so that the bufferedInputStream know when to stop reading.

Any idea what's wrong?

Sender Code:

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        Integer bytesRead = 0;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            objectOutStream.writeObject(bytesRead);
            bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        }
        System.out.println("Sucess sending file");
```

Receiver (Server):

```
       fileName = request.getFileName();
       int size = (int) request.getSize();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        int totalBytesReceived = 0;
        int blockSize = 0;
        while (totalBytesReceived < size) {
            Object o = ois.readObject();

            if (!(o instanceof Integer)) {
                System.out.println("Something is wrong");
            }
            blockSize = (Integer) o;

            buffer = new byte[blockSize];

            bis.read(buffer);
            totalBytesReceived += blockSize;
            fos.write(buffer, 0, blockSize);
        }
        System.out.println("File succes");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reading code on the server side should look the same as on the client side.

```
// copy from bis to bos, using a buffer.
for(int len; (len = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

On the client side you want

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
```

on the server side you want.

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
```

when finished you want to

```
bos.close();
bis.close();
```

If you are going to use an ObjectOutputStream (and I suggest you don't) you need to use only this stream, not a mixture of streams.

Comment: +1 for the ObjectOutputStream comment. I was just about to write that in my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code. You will get -1 from `bis.read()` when you reach the end of the stream. That way you don't need to know how long the file will be. And `flush()` and `close()` the streams on the server and client. As the other poster says, don't use `ObjectOutputStream` or `ObjectIntputStream`. You'll get serialization headers which will appear to corrupt your data.

```
   fileName = request.getFileName();

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    int data = bis.read(); //reads an int
    while (data != -1) {
        fos.write(data);
        data = bis.read();

    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    System.out.println("File succes");
```

Comment: `bis.read()` reads an unsigned byte.  `while(data += -1)` won't compile. `ois` isn't declared.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's just incorrect about bis.read(). Where in Java can you get an unsigned anything (except char)? From the docs: "Returns: the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached." The += was a typo, obviously. The ois nonsense was leftover from the OP's post. I'll fix.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not sure why you made the unsigned byte comment, so I went back and looked at the docs. read() returns a value from 0 to 255 in an int, -1 if end of stream is reached. Functions like an unsigned byte, but not a byte. write() takes an int that matches what read() returns.

Comment: Reading an `int` might imply it reads 4-bytes, instead it reads only one byte, but uses an `int` as there is 257 possible out comes.  You might wonder why short was not used.  I suspect it is because the JVM doesn't actually support types narrower than an `int` for the stack (return values and arguments) and types narrower than this actually use one 32-bit slot.