# A Java program (Standalone application) which sends 10MB file to another application/server takes lot of time

Tags: java, performance

A Java program (Standalone application) which sends 10MB file to another application/server takes lot of time.

What are the steps that I need to take care to improve the performance?
What tools I can use to identify and understand where the problem is?
How to identify if there is a problem with the network.. and what tools to use?

Comment: Compress the file. Split the file & send using threads... etc. Can you show any code?

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342134/sending-large-files-client-to-server?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177994/java-read-file-and-split-into-multiple-files

Comment: @Sharan : You have not given a detail on how you are sending the file ? Which protocol ? Are doing an HTTP call ? Is it a REST , SOAP ?

Comment: Show the code ([mcve]) and people can identify issues with that